# Change what is displayed based on selected options

Tags: jquery, html

How do I change this (http://jsfiddle.net/jRAAg/2/) so that depending on the combination I select from the dropdown it displays a different value above. For example, if I was to select just "Male" and "18-24", it should only show the scores corresponding to that selection. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
<div id="segmentscore" data-gender="1" data-age="0">100</div>
<div id="segmentaware" data-gender="1" data-age="0">150</div>

<div id="segmentscore" data-gender="1" data-age="2">190</div>
<div id="segmentaware" data-gender="1" data-age="2">100</div>


<div id="select1">
    <select id="genderlist">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">Male</option>
      <option value="2">Female</option>
  </select></div>
  <div id="select2"><select id="agelist">
    <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">12-17</option>
      <option value="2">18-24</option>
      <option value="3">25-34</option>
      <option value="4">35-44</option>
      <option value="5">45-54</option>
      <option value="6">55-99+</option>
  </select></div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#genderlist').on('change', function() {
  $('[data-gender]').each( function(index, element) {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  })
  gender = $('#genderlist')[0].value 
  $('[data-gender='+gender+']').each( function(index, element) {
    element.style.display = 'block'
  })
})
$('#agelist').on('change', function() {
  $('[data-age]').each( function(index, element) {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  })
  age = $('#agelist')[0].value
  $('[data-age='+age+']').each( function(index, element) {
    element.style.display = 'block'
  })
})
```

Comment: I don't see a clear relation between the 2 dropdowns

Comment: Your "javascript" looks a lot like jQuery.

Comment: so many `.each()` functions ... why the need for this many `.each()`s ...

Comment: You're jsfiddle isn't set to use jQuery. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/F69nk/. Also, your IDs should really be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I attempted to understand your question better. You have 2 drop down lists and when they are updated to equal scores you want then the values show. I have created a fiddle for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vsd3G/5/

HTML is largely unchanged - removed the duplicate ids, etc:

```
<div id="segmentscore"></div>
<div id="segmentaware"></div>
<div id="select1">
    <select id="genderlist">
    ...
    </select>
</div>
<div id="select2">
    <select id="agelist">
    ...
    </select>
</div>
```

I create an array of "scores" which specify your gender\age select index + scores and "aware" there.

```
var scores = [{
    gender: 1,
    ages: 1,
    score: 100,
    aware: 150
}, {
    gender: 1,
    ages: 2,
    score: 190,
    aware: 150
}];
```

I then declare the following variables for the scope of this app.

```
var genderValue, age;
```

Then the event handlers to determine if the correct things have been selected\set and what to do if they are.

```
$('#genderlist').on('change', function () {
    genderValue = $('#genderlist option:selected').val();
    if (age !== undefined)     {
        updateScore();
    }
});

$('#agelist').on('change', function () {
    age = $('#agelist option:selected').val();
    if (genderValue !== undefined)     {
        updateScore();
    }
});
```

Finally the update score function which will calculate whether a resulting score is found for that age\gender using underscore JS (http://underscorejs.org/). Specifically the _.where function.

Parseint is required as `.val()` returns us a string.

```
function updateScore() {
    var result = _.where(scores, {gender: parseInt(genderValue), ages: parseInt(age)})[0]; //assume 1 result always
    $('#segmentscore').text(result.score);
    $('#segmentaware').text(result.aware);
};
```

This way all you need to do is expand out the scores array above rather than creating more and more DOM elements to show\hide information, simply replace it with what you have. This also uses no foreachs at all.

Hope this helps and feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: If there is a better way to do this same thing, I'm completely open to it. I just don't know how, unfortunately.

Comment: I have some spare time presently so I will attempt to throw something together for you.